# True or false: $\left(\mu\left[a,\bar{a}\right]=\mu\left[b,\bar{b}\right]\iff a+\bar{b}=b+\bar{a}\right)\iff\mu$ is a homomorphism?

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, group-homomorphism

Note: square brackets $\left[\dots\right]$ are use to indicate parameter lists in function signatures.  Addition of ordered pairs in the domain is defined by

$$\left<a,\bar{a}\right>+\left<b,\bar{b}\right>=\left<a+b,\bar{a}+\bar{b}\right>.$$

The book I'm reading states without proof or clarification that a mapping of ordered pairs (of natural numbers $\{1,2,\dots\}$) is a homomorphism if and only if

$$\mu\left[a,\bar{a}\right]=\mu\left[b,\bar{b}\right]\iff a+\bar{b}=b+\bar{a}.\tag{1}$$

The codomain will end up being the integers, and $\mu$ will be subtraction.  But at this point all we have to work with are that addition is commutative, associative, and obeys a term-wise cancellation law $a+b=a+c\implies{b=c}$.

It is unclear to me if the authors intend the asserted property (1) to hold for all homomorphisms of ordered pairs, or they are talking about the specific case of integer subtraction.

I've tried to prove it for a generic homomorphic mapping of ordered pairs of natural numbers to some unspecified codomain in which there is addition having the stated properties.  But I haven't been able to come up with a proof.

Is the stated property (1) held by all homomorphisms with addition in the domain and codomain having the stated properties?  I'm not asking for a proof.  I'm only asking if the proposition is true.

Comment: A homomorphism? In which category? Are you talking about a homomorphism of groups, of modules over a ring, or what?

Comment: "A mapping with the property $\mu\left[a+b\right]=\mu\left[a\right]+\mu\left[b\right]$ is called a homomophism."  That's the same definition I have encountered in other textbooks.  Groups, rings, etc., have not yet been introduced.  Indeed, the homomorphism under discussion is used to introduce the first group and first ring discussed in the development.

Comment: Then you are supposing the domain and codomain of $\mu$ (which you have not specified) have an operation denoted by $+$ (which you have not defined). So, what are the domain and codomain of your $\mu$, and what is the $+$ operation on each? Possibly these are mentioned in your book (which you have not cited).

Comment: I believe I have provided all of the relevant information.  I did specify the domain.  And the codomain is essentially defined by the homomorphism and addition with the specified properties, also given in my question.

Comment: You have not specified the addition on your domain (is that $\Bbb N^2$?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a counterexample:

Consider the map $\mu\colon\Bbb N^2\to\Bbb N$ by $\mu(x,y)=y$. Then,

$$\mu(a,\bar a)+\mu(b,\bar b)=\bar a+\bar b=\mu(x,\bar a+\bar b)=\mu(a+b,\bar a+\bar b)$$

So, $\mu$ is a homomorphism, but,

$$\mu(a,\bar a)=\mu(b,\bar b)\implies \bar a=\bar b$$

so $a$ and $b$ can be any natural number, so $a+\bar b=b+\bar a$ doesn't necessarily hold. For example, $\mu(1,2)=\mu(3,2)=2$ but $1+2=3\neq 5=3+2$

Comment: Now all I need to do is figure out what they meant by saying that $\mu$ is a homomorphism if and only if it satisfies property (1).  In this case $\mu\left[a,\bar{a}\right]$ is the solution of the equation $a=x+\bar{a}$ where it may be the case that $\bar{a}<a,$ both of them being natural numbers.  But that's a different question.